# Swiper Component not working in React and throwing Erros

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

So I am following along with a course by Traversy Media called "React Front To Back 2022", at the 16th section of the course in the 5th and 6th videos, he was using the Swiper component. I was following along step-by-step but at the end, it threw an error, so after a bit of thinking and googling I decided to see the solution of the GitHub repository posted by him of the project, I compared the code, seemed the same, I copied it, still, it threw the errors and didn't render the page.

I couldn't find a fix anywhere(google, documentation, youtube, etc), so hopefully someone can help me here. Thank you in advance for the help.

The Errors:

```
init-swiper.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pagination')
at mountSwiper (init-swiper.js:25:1)
at swiper.js:136:1
at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23049:1)
at invokeLayoutEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25010:1)
at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27304:1)
at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27280:1)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27007:1)
at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26032:1)
at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12009:1)

react_devtools_backend.js:4026 The above error occurred in the <Swiper> component:

at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:131862:66
at Slider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1549:66)
at main
at div
at Explore
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:120121:24)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:120046:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:118774:23)
at App

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pagination')
at mountSwiper (init-swiper.js:25:1)
at swiper.js:136:1
at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23049:1)
at invokeLayoutEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25010:1)
at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27304:1)
at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27280:1)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27007:1)
at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26032:1)
at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12009:1)
```

**The Code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { collection, getDocs, query, orderBy, limit } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../firebase.config'
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'
import Spinner from './Spinner'
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y])

function Slider() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [listings, setListings] = useState(null)

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchListings = async () => {
      const listingsRef = collection(db, 'listings')
      const q = query(listingsRef, orderBy('timestamp', 'desc'), limit(5))
      const querySnap = await getDocs(q)

      let listings = []

      querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
        return listings.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        })
      })

      setListings(listings)
      setLoading(false)
    }

    fetchListings()
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />
  }

  if (listings.length === 0) {
    return <></>
  }

  return (
    listings && (
      <>
        <p className='exploreHeading'>Recommended</p>

        <Swiper slidesPerView={1} pagination={{ clickable: true }}>
          {listings.map(({ data, id }) => (
            <SwiperSlide
              key={id}
              onClick={() => navigate(`/category/${data.type}/${id}`)}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  background: `url(${data.imgUrls[0]}) center no-repeat`,
                  backgroundSize: 'cover',
                }}
                className='swiperSlideDiv'
              >
                <p className='swiperSlideText'>{data.name}</p>
                <p className='swiperSlidePrice'>
                  ${data.discountedPrice ?? data.regularPrice}{' '}
                  {data.type === 'rent' && '/ month'}
                </p>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </>
    )
  )
}

export default Slider
```

[GitHub link to the repo](https://github.com/bradtraversy/house-marketplace/blob/main/src/components/Slider.jsx)

Answer (score 2):

```
I'm currently facing same issue while following the course On udemy can't seem to find any difference in my code. The fix was, I updated Swiper to the latest version using npm i swiper@latest then changed my imports to import  {Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import 'swiper/css'
 and finally updated my swiper components to <Swiper
        slidesPerView={1}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
        navigation
        scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      >
        {listing.imgUrls.map((url, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <div
              style={{
                background: `url(${listing.imgUrls[index]}) center no-repeat`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                minHeight: '26rem',
              }}
              className='swiperSlideDiv'
            ></div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching versions for switcher package.

Checkout the package.json of traversary's repo: https://github.com/bradtraversy/house-marketplace/blob/main/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Its coming due to <react.strictmode> remove it from index.js and it works but I don't know why strict mode causes this error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).